# Red Dwarf episode in period costume where a time travelling assassin droid or simulant out to kill Lister or one of the others

Tags: episode-identification, red-dwarf

Nope, not a quiz game...

I've been racking my brain and reading the Wikipedia synopsis of each episode trying to work out which one I'm thinking of. If it is even a *Red Dwarf* episode!

It involves period costume I think in the style of Pride and Prejudice, and a time travelling assassin droid or simulant out to kill Lister or one of the others.  There's a period house, and a scene in the dining room with a confrontation between the assassin droid and our heroes.  The assassin droid might have been in black armour.

It's not "The Inquisitor" episode, that's for certain, and it's not the episode where Kryten drives a tank up out of a lake.  It's not the wax droids in a war episode, "Meltdown", either.

Comment: [Twentica](https://reddwarf.fandom.com/wiki/RD:_Twentica) It's a series 11 one, so I've never actually watched it, but it's the only hit for "period costume" on the wiki.

Comment: @Jontia no, not that one either.

Comment: The closest episode I can think of for this is ["Beyond a Joke"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_a_Joke_(Red_Dwarf)) but that's the one where Kryten drives the tank out of the lake so not that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm starting to think it's not a Red Dwarf episode at all, but I'm sure it is - the setup seems too ridiculous to not be and the humour (that I recall) fits Red Dwarf perfectly. What other show could it be?

Comment: Time travelling assassin droid with period costumes sounds like an episode of Doctor Who (I think during David Tennant's run as The Doctor), but that doesn't really have the humour of Red Dwarf.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that would be [The Girl in the Fireplace](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Girl_in_the_Fireplace_(TV_story)), but there's no dining room.

Comment: Nope, definitely not Dr Who, can't stand that show.

Answer (score 9):

The period costume dinner is S7E6 "Beyond a Joke". Excerpts from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_a_Joke_(Red_Dwarf)):

> Meanwhile, Kochanski decides to educate Lister and Cat on the finer points of etiquette by introducing them to a virtual reality rendition of "Pride and Prejudice Land" in "Jane Austen World".
>
> [...]
>
> Lister suggests that they board the SS Centauri again and look for some spare mechanoid heads there. However, they discover a Rogue Simulant captain who has since commandeered the Centauri.

This is no time travel though, and the droid confronting our heroes at dinner is Kryten.

[image: Dwarfers at period costume dinner]

You may be conflating this with S3E6 "The Last Day", which also features a dinner party and a black-armoured droid.

[image: Dinner from "The Last Day"]
[image: Hudzen 5]

The only time-travelling droid/simulant in pre-Series X *Red Dwarf* (other than Kryten) is The Inquisitor, which you have already excluded.

Comment: The OP specifically rules this episode out _"it's not the episode where Kryten drives a tank up out of a lake"_. Also see my comment stating it sounds like this one except for the tank bit which the OP rules out.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot they may be mistaken

Comment: Considering they ruled it out in the question and didn't go "oops my mistake it is that one" in the comments when I suggested it I highly doubt they are.

Comment: No, it's neither of those.  The scenes I'm after are very very clear in my mind.

Comment: @Moo then I'm pretty certain it's not Red Dwarf.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm thinking that too, or it was a charity special.

Answer (score 5):

Are you thinking of episode 7.2 "[Stoke Me A Clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoke_Me_a_Clipper)"?

The period costume element may be the AR game Lister is playing in which he is cast as a jousting knight.

Later in the episode, Lister pretends to be a knight in black (and red) armour which has supposedly escaped from the AR machine and is seeking to kill the crew. This is a ruse so that Rimmer can perform a heroic act and convince him that he can take over the role of 'Ace'. Lister later tells Kryten and Cat that the AR Knight has "killed" Arnold Rimmer as a cover story for him leaving the crew as Ace's replacement.

There is no "dining room scene" as you described, but it seems a better fit than the suggestions you rejected. Lister's character in the AR at the start of the episode ("Lister of Smeg") *is* dressed all in black. Also, he approaches the King and makes his jousting challenge at a sort of medieval feast event which may be what you remember.